# Cannot open my client

Tags: python, tryton

I am trying to open my `tryton` client but it is not working
the snapshot of my problem :
[image]

the text of the problem is:

```
  File "./tryton", line 66, in <module>
    tryton.client.TrytonClient().run()

  File "/home/ghassen/work/tryton/tryton/client.py", line 101, in run
    main.sig_login()

  File "/home/ghassen/work/tryton/tryton/gui/main.py", line 910, in sig_login
    res = DBLogin().run()

  File "/home/ghassen/work/tryton/tryton/gui/window/dblogin.py", line 579, in run
    if (self.profiles.get(profile_name, sectionname)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tryton has a profile file where it saves the know connections, and from the error it seems that file is corrupted. You can find this file under  ~/.config/tryton/x.y/profiles.cfg where x.y corresponds to you version number.

If you don't have any saved profile, you can remove this file and the client will recreate them when started another time.